# Pick a number randomly from two numbers

Tags: java, random

I have two integers, let them be

```
int a = 35:
int b = 70;
```

I want to pick one of them randomly at runtime and assign to another variable. I.e.

```
int c = a or b:
```

One of the ways that come into my mind is to create an array with these two integers and find a random integer between 0 and 1 and use it as the index of the array to get the number..

Or randomize boolean and use it in if-else.

My question is that is there a better and more efficient way to achieve this? I.e. pick a number from two previously defined integers?

Comment: I think your 0/1 rand int solution works fine

Comment: More of a side note: I'd say that if it will always just be 2 integers then using `random.nextBoolean()` is the easiest way to go. Using the array and index variant would be easier to extend to more than 2 values though. Additionally, should you require a different weight for the 2 integers, you could roll your own `boolean nextBoolean(float probabilityForTrue ) { return random.nextFloat() < probabilityForTrue; }`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is there a specific reason you are asking for a more efficient solution? Unless this functionality sits in a very tight inner loop somewhere (e.g. in a ray tracer), you might be trying to *prematurely optimize* your code.

If you would like to avoid the array, and if you don't like the "bloat" of an if-statement, you can use the ternary choice operator to pick between the two:

```
int a = 35;
int b = 70;
int c = random.nextBoolean() ? a : b;
```

where `random` is an instance of `java.util.Random`. You can store this instance as a `final static` field in your class to reuse it.

If you don't require true randomness, but just want to switch between the two numbers in each invocation of the given block of code, you can get away with just storing a `boolean` and toggling it:

```
...
int c = toggle ? a : b;
toggle = !toggle;
```

Since I can't comment on other answers, I'd like to point out an issue with some of the other answers that suggest generating a random integer in a bigger range and making a decision based on whether the result is odd or even, or if it's lower or greater than the middle value. This is in effect the exact same thing as generating a random integer between 0 and 1, except overly complicated. The `nextInt(n)` method [uses the modulo operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) on a randomly generated integer between -2^31 and (2^31)-1, which is essentially what you will be doing in the end anyway, just with `n = 2`.

If you are using the standard library methods like `Collections.shuffle()`, you will again be overcomplicating things, because the standard library uses the random number generator of the standard library.

Note that all of the suggestions (so far) are *less* efficient than my simple `nextBoolean()` suggestion, because they require unnecessary method calls and arithmetic.

Comment: Indeed the other suggestions are less efficient than simply getting a random boolean. However, OP specifically asked for such solutions! :P But yeah, yours in _the_ answer.

Comment: OP asked for *better* and *more efficient* solutions, and the provided answers are less efficient. Whether they are *better* is a matter of opinion, I think. Personally, I prefer readable code to overcomplicated code.

Answer (score 6):

Another way to do this is, store the numbers into a list, shuffle, and take the first element.

```
ArrayList<Integer> numbers=new ArrayList<Integer>();
numbers.add(35);
numbers.add(70);
Collections.shuffle(numbers);

numbers.get(0);
```

Comment: Aren't we creating a large overhead here by using whole ArrayList? It's gotta be expensive. Also, shuffling collection with two members should be same as calling new random out of two numbers, right?

Comment: Yes. technically it [use random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html). but as I said, it is just another way to do it

Comment: in fact, this way is pretty good when we want to choose between a three of four specif numbers.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, main problem here is entropy for two numbers rather than making use of that entropy. Indexed array or boolean are essentially the same thing. What else you can do (and, hopefully, it will be more random) is to make Java give you a random number between limits say 0 to 100. Now, if the chosen random number is odd, you pick `int c = a`. Pick `b` otherwise. I could be wrong, but picking random between 0 to 100 seems more random as compared to picking random between two numbers.

Comment: That seems better.. There will definitely be more randomness with this.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use secure random generator(`java.security.SecureRandom` ).

```
try {
    r = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
    boolean b1 = r.nextBoolean(); 

    if (b1) {
        c = a;
    } else {
        c = b;
    }
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae) {
    // Process the exception in some way or the other
}
```

Refer this link for more [information](http://www.componentix.com/blog/6/using-cryptographically-strong-random-number-generator-with-securerandom-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Randomize an integer between 1 and 10, if it's more than 5 then take the value of b other wise go with a. As far as I know there are no other ways to select from integers.

Comment: Your solution is similar to that of @akshay2000 but i think picking even odd solution is more random

Comment: Yea.. Do something like this

Answer (score 0):

```
int a=1;
int b=2;
int get = new Random().nextBoolean()? a : b;
```